# Breeze Expand not working on WebAPI with EF

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I have published a WebAPI service which returns a list of items. I am implementing Breeze and have managed to get it basically working with filtering/sorting. However, the Expand is not working.

[http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/dares?$expand=ToUser](http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/dares?%24expand=ToUser)

You can see the ToUserId ForeignKey in the response above, but the ToUser properties are NULL (the user definitely exists)

You can see the ToUser EF navigation property in the metadata.

When I use **.Include** on the server side I can populate it with EF, but I don't want to do this.

I checked the Breeze Tutorial 2 here on Expand: http://learn.breezejs.com/
Here is it without expand:  http://learn.breezejs.com/api/northwind/Products

and here it is with Expand (And you can see the additional Category info): [http://learn.breezejs.com/api/northwind/Products?$expand=Category](http://learn.breezejs.com/api/northwind/Products?%24expand=Category)

This is what I am trying to do but mine does not fill it...

**UPDATE:**
I downloaded the [Breeze 1.3.6 Samples](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download) and loaded the DocCode solution in VS2011.
I ran it and saw that the client-side expand works;
e.g.
`http://localhost:47595/breeze/Northwind/Orders?$top=1`   (no expand)
`http://localhost:47595/breeze/Northwind/Orders?$top=1&$expand=Customer`  (expands customer correctly).

I checked the WebAPI controller code and it looks the same, except they use EF Code First instead of Model First. The Foreign key is decorated with a property:

**Breeze Sample that Works**

```
[ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
[InverseProperty("Orders")]
public Customer Customer {get; set;}
```

It just doesn't make sense... it is something to do with my WebAPI controller or EntityFramework relationship...

**UPDATE 2**
I downloaded the most basic ToDo Knockout Breeze sample and added this line to the ToDoItem class: `public User ToUser { get; set; }`
I am then able to Expand the WebAPI call `with http://localhost:63030/breeze/todos/Todos?$expand=ToUser`

So I have come to the conclusion that it is something to do with the fact that I am using EntityFramework DB First and not Code First. It definitely does seem possible to do in the current version of the WebAPI with Breeze and EF.

**UPDATE 3**
I have narrowed it down to my database, EF Database First and Code First differences, but still not identified the issue. I have changed from a Model to a Code First approach with the exact same result (ie. no expand).

For example: if you look at this Expand on the Breeze site that works, http://learn.breezejs.com/api/northwind/Products?%24expand=Category, try change the last param to an invalid field and it throws an error, e.g. :
http://learn.breezejs.com/api/northwind/Products?%24expand=Category1

However, in my code, it always ignores this param and returns ALL the records, and never throws an exception if the Expand param is incorrect:
[http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/dares?$expand=To4657657User](http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/dares?%24expand=To4657657User)

Hence I am stumped.. I have no idea why this is not working.

**My Code**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Dares()
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, (IQueryable<Dare>)contextProvider.Context.Dares);
        return ControllerUtilities.GetResponseWithCorsHeader(response);
    }
```

and here is the generated class from my EF model (using Database First)

```
public partial class Dare
{
    public int DareId { get; set; }
    public int ToUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User ToUser { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the problem - the IQueryable with the HttpResponseMessage  return type does not behave the same as a pure IQueryable return type. expand seems to work when I do not wrap it.

I have raised a new question here:
[How to use Breeze IQueryable with CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475435/how-to-use-breeze-iqueryable-with-cors)

Answer (score 1):

Your URL seems to be missing the `$` for the expand query option...should be `$expand`.

Comment: $select & $expand support is part of the latest Beta Preview bits released few days back. FYI: http://www.asp.net/vnext

Comment: FYI:  I have updated my question to fix the $ and also include URLS from the Breeze Tutorials, where Expand works.

Comment: Re. Beta Preview: I don't understand this- how does the Breeze tutorial example work? Are you saying that this is a Web API issue (not a Breeze issue)? I am battling to comprehend where 1 technology starts and the other ends. And are there any workarounds in the meantime...

Comment: ps - here is the direct link to the reference you made above re. 2013 beta - ps - here is the direct link to the reference you made above re. 2013 beta - http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/release-notes#TOC11.  The part I still don't get is how Breeze is working in the tutorial and all the examples which use Expand - are they using the Beta on the Web API side?

Comment: @Rodney: which examples are your referring to?

Comment: I updated my question - it's in the live tutorial 2 on http://learn.breezejs.com/  (if you run Google Debugger you can see expand working:  http://learn.breezejs.com/api/northwind/Products?%24expand=Category)

Comment: Ok, I have added more info - after downloading the Breeze sample I can see that they have it working with the WebAPI.. which means I am even more confused!